# Laravel Function Not Updating Database

Tags: laravel-5

I am calling the function below

```
 function makeanote($type,$id){
$note = Notification::where("user_id",Auth::user()->id)->get();
if ($type == "user"){
if($id > $note->pluck("users") ){
$note->users = $id;
$note->save();  
return;
}   
}
return;
           }
```

Like so: `makeanote($type,$id)`. The calling `$type` is `"user"` and the calling `$id` is `"31"`.

In the database for my current user, the `$note` value at the users column is currently zero (`0`).

Therefore I would expect it to update to 31, but it is staying at zero. Am I using `pluck()` incorrectly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
function makeanote($type,$id){
$note = Notification::where("user_id",Auth::user()->id)->first();
if ($type == "user"){
if($id > $note->users){
$note->users = $id;
$note->save();  
return;
}   
}
return;
       }
```

My changes are: `->first()` (this will return a single object) instead of `->get()` (this returns a object collection) and once you have the object you can access the `users` attribute directly.

Comment: Cheers, just so people notice in the future, the key was `first()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: ya, sorry - I realized it wasn't so clear so I added some explanation to the answer...